# How to check if function is declared in global scope at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, opengl

Let I have a header, for example `#include <GL/gl.h>`. It contains subset of OpenGL API functions. I need something like this:

```
static_assert(has_glDrawArraysIndirect::value, "There is no glDrawArraysIndirect");
```

Or even better:

```
PFNGLDRAWARRAYSINSTANCEDPROC ptr_glDrawArraysIndirect = ptr_to_glDrawArraysIndirect::ptr;
```

Where `ptr_to_glDrawArraysIndirect::ptr` unrolls to pointer to glDrawArraysIndirect if it's defined or to a stub function `stub_glDrawArraysIndirect` otherwise.

My target operating system is very specific. Any linker based solution (like `GetProcAddress` or `dlsym`) doesn't work for me, since there is no dynamic linker. More than, my driver doesn't provide `glXGetProcAdrress` nor `wglGetProcAddress`, basically there there is no way to query pointer at run time by function name (Actually, I want to implement such a mechanism).

Any ideas?

Comment: If there is no dynamic linking, then it must be statically linked. So either the function exists at compile time or it doesn't. And since that will be determined by the contents of a header, you could just look through that.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: This is what I was doing for a long time. Since the driver is under heavy development, I'm tired of updating my code. I wanna solve it once in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer that can detect it at compile time and produce a boolean value. It works by creating a template function of the same name in a namespace and then using that namespace inside of the `is_defined()` function. If the real `glDrawArraysIndirect()` exists it will take preference over the template version. If you comment out the first declaration of `glDrawArraysIndirect()` the static assert at the bottom will trigger.

[<kbd>Test on GodBolt</kbd>](https://goo.gl/35k94K)

```
#include <type_traits>

enum GLenum {};

void glDrawArraysIndirect(GLenum, const void*);

namespace detail {
    struct dummy;

    template<typename T>
    dummy& glDrawArraysIndirect(T, const void*);
}

constexpr bool is_defined()
{
    using namespace detail;
    using ftype = decltype(glDrawArraysIndirect(GLenum(), nullptr));
    return std::is_same<ftype, void>();
}

static_assert(is_defined(), "not defined");
```

With a little tweak you can make your custom function the template and use a similar trick

[<kbd>ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Ci3nSc)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//#define USE_REAL

enum GLenum {TEST};

typedef void (*func_type)(GLenum, const void*);

#ifdef USE_REAL
void glDrawArraysIndirect(GLenum, const void*);
#endif

namespace detail {
    struct dummy {};

    template<typename T = dummy>
    void glDrawArraysIndirect(GLenum, const void*, T = T())
    {
        std::cout << "In placeholder function" << std::endl;
    }

}

void wrapDraw(GLenum x, const void* y)
{
  using namespace detail;
  glDrawArraysIndirect(x, y);
}

#ifdef USE_REAL
void glDrawArraysIndirect(GLenum, const void*)
{
    std::cout << "In real function" << std::endl;
}
#endif

int main()
{
    wrapDraw(TEST, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Actually, for the second example you don't need the namespace or dummy or default template argument at all. Just let the `T` generic type take the place of `GLenum` and it will be selected behind the real one in overload resolution.

Comment: Doing so potentially reduces type safety and can generate multiple template instantiations depending on the type inferred for the T you're using for the enum. That's why I went with this approach.

Comment: @KurtStutsman: Well, you could add a `static_assert` to enforce `T` to be `GLenum`.

Comment: Is the detail namespace necessary?

Comment: It shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 3):

Include the expression `sizeof(::function)` somewhere. (If the function exists then asking for the size of the pointer to the function is a perfectly valid thing to do).

It will be benign at runtime, and `::` forces the use of the `function` declared at global scope.

Of course, if `function` does not exist at global scope, then compilation will fail.

Along with other errors, the compiler will issue a specific error if you were to write something on the lines of

`static_assert(sizeof(::function), "There is no global function");`

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(::function), "There is no global function");`

Comment: Bonus points if you figure out how to detect presence of a function and assign 1 to a `bool` constant if it exists and 0 otherwise, instead of aborting compilation.

Answer (score 1):

> My target operating system is very specific. Any linker based solution (like GetProcAddress or dlsym) doesn't work for me, since there is no dynamic linker.

Is this an embedded system or just a weirdly stripped down OS running on standard PC hardware?

> More than, my driver doesn't provide glXGetProcAdrress nor wglGetProcAddress, basically there there is no way to query pointer at run time by function name

The abiliy to query function pointers at runtime does not depend on the presence of a dynamic linker. Those two are completely orthogonal and even a purely statically linked embedded OpenGL implementation can offer a `GetProcAddress` interface just fine. Instead of trying to somehow solve the problem at compile or link time, I'd rather address the problem by implementing a `GetProcAddress` for your OpenGL driver; you can do that even if the driver is available as only a static library in binary form. Step one:

Create function pointer stubs for each and every OpenGL function, statically initialized to NULL and attributed weak linkage. Link this into a static library you may call `gl_null_stubs` or similar.

Create a `GetProcAddress` function that for every OpenGL function there is returns the pointer to the function symbol within the scope of the function's compilation unit.

Now link your weird OpenGL driver with the stubs library and the `GetProcAddress` implementation. For every function there is, the weak linkage of the stub will the static library symbol to take precedence. For all OpenGL symbols not in your driver the stubs will take over.

There: Now you have a OpenGL driver library that *has* a GetProcAddress implementation. That wasn't that hard, was it?

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if function is declared in global scope at compile time?
>   My target operating system is very specific...

A possible solution might be, if you are using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -probably as a cross-compiler for your weird target OS and ABI- to customize the `gcc` (or `g++` etc...) compiler with your own [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension.

MELT is a domain specific language, implemented as a free software GCC plugin (mostly on Linux), to customize the GCC compiler.